# Pandas read csv replacing #DIV/0! and #VALUE! with NaN

Tags: python, excel, csv, replace, pandas

I am new to Pandas for Python and am busy reading a csv file. Unfortunately the Excel file has some cells with #VALUE! and #DIV/0! in them. I cannot fix this in Excel because the data is pulled from other sheets. Pandas turns these columns into `objects` instead of `numpy64`, so I cannot plot from them. I want to replace the #VALUE! and #DIV/0! strings with NaN entries in Pandas, however i cannot find how to do this. I have tried the following (my code runs, but it changes nothing):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('2013AllData.csv')
df.replace('#DIV/0!', np.nan)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than replacing after loading, just set the param `na_values` when reading the csv in and it will convert them to `NaN` values when the df is created:

```
df = pd.read_csv('2013AllData.csv', na_values=['#VALUE!', '#DIV/0!'])
```

Check the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv

Comment: And if one wants to do the opposite - to know where there is an error in the excel and let the developer know? is there a way to handle that?